# Spring MVC / Spring Data data fetch recursion

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, fasterxml

I have an entity with `one-to-many relationship` (for ex. `Person o->m Book`). If I want to fetch a person with books in controller, it causes recursion. `@JsonIgnore` by `FasterXML` helps, but what if I want `bidirectional` fetch without recursion. For example fetch `Person with Books` and fetch `Book with Persons`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use @JsonBackReference

```
class Person{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Book> books; 
    ...
}

class Book { 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(columnDefinition="integer", name = "person", nullable=false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Person person;
    ...
}
```